# SQLite Error 7: Out of memory

Tags: sqlite

I have been interacting with my SQLite database without problem for some time, but now I just keep on getting the error

```
SQLite Error 7: 'out of memory'
```

whenever I try to open my SQLite database connection. Is my storage exhausted or what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Seems like I was trying to open the database when it was already opened in another function.